# jax-rs GlassFish4 upload file

Tags: eclipse, file-upload, glassfish, jax-rs

Good day

I use EclipseEE Luna,Win7 32bit,Java 8_45 and GlassFish 4.1 as AS. I create standard dynamic project without Maven. I want use web service jax-rs to upload selected file to defined folder. I use example from (http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/). When I want upload(deploy) the GlassFish in Eclipse show me the error and the project will not load to AS. I really do not know what do I bad. Have I do something bad? Or have I forgot something?

```
cannot Deploy Java.REST02.GlassFish4.HtmlForm
deploy is failing=Application with name [Java.REST02.GlassFish4.HtmlForm] is not deployed
```

Application :

```
package server;
import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import service3.fileupload.*;
@ApplicationPath("server")
public class Server extends Application {
    private final Set<Class<?>> classes;
    public Server() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> c = new HashSet<>();
        c.add(RestService3.class);
        classes = Collections.unmodifiableSet(c);   }
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return classes; }
}
```

RestService :

```
package service3.fileupload;
import java.io.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.*;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;  
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;  
@Path("service3")
public class RestService3 {
    @GET
    @Path("test3")
    public String testMetodaString(){
        System.out.println("Vypis - 3");
        return "TEST-vypis3";   }
    //      DO NOT WORK - BY LOADING TO AS IT CRASH
    @POST
    @Path("upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile( @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                                @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {
        String uploadedFileLocation = "D:\\Download\\" + fileDetail.getFileName();
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);
        String output = "Soubor uložen : " + uploadedFileLocation;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 
    }
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,String uploadedFileLocation) {     // save uploaded file to new location
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);  }
            out.flush();
            out.close();    }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    }   }
}
```

HTML PAGE :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>WebPage test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Zde test upload souboru pres jax-rs :</h1><br>
<form action="/server/service3/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
    Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45""/></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Nahraj Soubor" /></form>
</body>
</html>
```

I use only GlassFish System Library :

```
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\bean-validator.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\cdi-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\endorsed\javax.annotation-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\endorsed\jaxb-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\endorsed\webservices-api-osgi.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\glassfish-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\ha-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.batch-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.ejb-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.el.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.concurrent-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.concurrent.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.enterprise.deploy-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.faces.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.inject.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.interceptor-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.jms-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.json.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.mail.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.management.j2ee-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.persistence.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.resource-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.security.auth.message-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.security.jacc-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.transaction-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.websocket-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.ws.rs-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.xml.registry-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\javax.xml.rpc-api.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jaxb-extra-osgi.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jaxb-osgi.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-bean-validation.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-client.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-common.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-grizzly2-http.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-container-servlet.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-entity-filtering.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-gf-cdi.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-gf-ejb.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-guava.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-jackson.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-jettison.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-json-processing.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-moxy.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-multipart.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-media-sse.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc-connector.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc-jsp.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-mvc.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\jersey-server.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.antlr.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.asm.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.dbws.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.moxy.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\org.eclipse.persistence.oracle.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\webservices-connector.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\webservices-extra-jdk-packages.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\webservices-osgi.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\webservices.security.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\glassfish\modules\weld-osgi-bundle.jar
C:\Program Files\JavaEE\mq\lib\jaxm-api.jar
```

Logs from Glassfish4  glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log

```
[2015-06-30T08:48:23.755+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903303] [timeMillis: 1435646903755] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:23.755+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903303] [timeMillis: 1435646903755] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:24.130+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903334] [timeMillis: 1435646904130] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:24.145+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903334] [timeMillis: 1435646904145] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:24.161+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903334] [timeMillis: 1435646904161] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:24.879+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903334] [timeMillis: 1435646904879] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:24.894+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100] [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=14 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903287] [timeMillis: 1435646904894] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:25.581+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903334] [timeMillis: 1435646905581] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 406ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:25.643+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903334] [timeMillis: 1435646905643] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:25.659+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903334] [timeMillis: 1435646905659] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:25.752+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=15 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903303] [timeMillis: 1435646905752] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 15ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:25.752+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1435646905752] [levelValue: 800] [[
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (6 366ms), startup services(2 480ms), total(8 846ms)]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:26.205+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1435646903334] [timeMillis: 1435646906205] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:26.361+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1435646906361] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@3ed581 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@1967222.]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:26.579+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=54 _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1435646906579] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://ntbHP:8686/jndi/rmi://ntbHP:8686/jmxrmi]]

[2015-06-30T08:48:28.105+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1435646908105] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final]]
```

Logs from Elipse Console by starting GlasFish with added project :

```
2015-06-30T09:19:00.539+0200|Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
2015-06-30T09:19:00.554+0200|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2015-06-30T09:19:01.054+0200|Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-06-30T09:19:01.069+0200|Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-06-30T09:19:01.085+0200|Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2015-06-30T09:19:01.880+0200|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2015-06-30T09:19:02.052+0200|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2015-06-30T09:19:02.723+0200|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 421ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2015-06-30T09:19:02.770+0200|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 16ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2015-06-30T09:19:02.770+0200|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2015-06-30T09:19:02.848+0200|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2015-06-30T09:19:02.848+0200|Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (5�242ms), startup services(2�746ms), total(7�988ms)
2015-06-30T09:19:03.238+0200|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 0ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
2015-06-30T09:19:03.472+0200|Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@7dfd44 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@2eea2a.
2015-06-30T09:19:03.768+0200|Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://ntbHP:8686/jndi/rmi://ntbHP:8686/jmxrmi
2015-06-30T09:19:05.827+0200|Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
```

Comment: That tutorial is using Jersey 1.x. Glassfish4 uses Jersey 2.x. These two Jersey major version do not sit well together. Did you include all those dependencies from the tutorial into your project?

Comment: Yes, but it not work,too.

Comment: Remove all the dependencies you found in the tutorial. You seem to already have the required 2.x multipart suport. No need for the 1.x support. Also make sure to register the `MultiPartFeature`. Also do you have a complete stacktrace/server error log?

Comment: For better help, please post your app configuration, all your dependencies, and the complete error log

Comment: Sorry, for my bad last message. I do not use Maven. I use only GlassFish jar in project. Thank you for you fast answer.

Comment: Please show the complete error log, also make sure you register the `MultiPartFeature` in the application  i.e `c.add(MultiPartFeature.class)` Failing to do so will cause a model validation error and cause a launch failure.

Comment: I added the logs but i thing there is nothing to help. And I add the c.add(MultiPartFeature.class) and does not help. The project is not deploy.

Comment: Is there no stacktrace anywhere, like in the console, when you start the server. Normally there is some trace that the application has failed to launch

Comment: Did you try to build the war and manually deploy it to Glassfish, instead of through Eclipse?

Comment: I added Eclipse Console output. There is really nothing to find where is the problem. If I delete methods  : public Response uploadFile and private void writeToFile , the project deploy in IDE correctly and from IE is method public String testMetodaString() work correctly.  No I do not build war file. I will do it(test it) and write here how look like.

Comment: I export it to *.war file and added throw gui admin console to GlassFish. **It deploy correctly**. It is really weird.  If I use upload-file method with url it is work correctly too.  ** It is very weird **. So I thing it is solved. Problem look like is in Eclipse.